# Absolute value and adding to a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi guys I'm using Python and I'm trying to write a function that takes a list and an option (1 or 0). If the option is 0 it returns a new list with all the numbers that have an absolute value greater than 5 and if the option is 1 then it returns all the odd numbers.

I almost have the 0 option working, but when I try to get back a list it just keeps it blank and I was wondering if maybe someone could help me find what I'm doing wrong with appending the element of the list.

My code so far:

```
def splitList(myList, option):
    myList = []
    myList2 = []
    if option == 0:
        for element in myList:
            if abs(element)>5:
                myList2.append(element)
    print(myList2)
```

Comment: You're not returning `myList2` from the function... (not to mention you're setting `myList` to be empty straight away...)

Comment: YJust do `return myList2` after the loop. Also for the other scenario, `if element % 2 == 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to *return* the result from the function; add a`return` statement at the end:

```
return myList2
```

Also, you rebind `myList` to an empty list at the start of the function; remove that line alltogether; otherwise you are ignoring the `myList` argument passed to the function:

```
def splitList(myList, option):
    myList2 = []
    if option == 0:
        for element in myList:
            if abs(element)>5:
                myList2.append(element)
    return myList2
```

You could simplify the loop to using a list comprehension:

```
def splitList(myList, option):
    if option == 0:
        return [el for el in myList if abs(el) > 5]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help that made it work perfectly. Also credit to @Tim Pietzcker for pointing that out first.

Answer (score 3):

You're accepting an argument for a list, but then locally overriding it to [], so of course, myList is empty before it goes into the for loop

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily with [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
def splitList(myList,option):
  if option==0:
    return [x for x in myList if abs(x)>5]
  return [x for x in myList if (x%2)==1]
```